# how to get the path of selected list item in python

Tags: python, wxpython

I am making a music player. I am trying to add a feature that is a listbox of all the songs in the "songs" folder/directory. I have it to where the songs show up in the listbox, but how would I go about getting the songs to play once they are selected in the listbox?

HERE IS SOME OF MY CODE:

```
    songlist = os.listdir('songs')
    listbox = wx.ListBox(panel2, -1, (10,200), (140,200), songlist, wx.LB_SINGLE)

    self.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED, self.selLoadFile, listbox)
```

this is the code for my listbox. What would my selLoadFile function look like?

Answer (score 1):

```
def selLoadFile(self,evt):
    my_selection = self.myListBox.GetStrings()[self.myListBox.GetSelection()]
    file_path = os.path.join(os.os.getcwd(),"songs",)
    print "My File Selected:",file_path
    #play song somehow
```

but you need to save some reference to the listbox

Comment: What are you trying to say by reference?

Comment: `self.myListBox = listbox = wx.ListBox(panel2, -1, (10,200), (140,200), songlist, wx.LB_SINGLE)`

Comment: still wont work.. maybe I'm trying to play it wrong? can we chat again and ill send you some more of my code?

Comment: sure ill be back in 15 or 20 mins and then ill help you get it working
If you could make one file that shows your whole problem that would help